# Using FileWriter and BufferedWriter clearing file for some reason?

Tags: java, io, filewriter, bufferedwriter

For some reason, when I create a new BufferedWriter and FileWriter in my program (Even if I haven't used it to write anything yet), it clears the file I have selected of all it's text.

selectedFile is determined by a JFileChooser.

```
public static File selectedFile;

    public static void Encrypt() throws Exception {

    try {
        //if I comment these two writers out the file is not cleared.
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(selectedFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(selectedFile.toString()),
                Charset.defaultCharset());
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println(AESencrp.encrypt(line));

            /*file is cleared regardless of whether or not these are commented out or
             * not, as long as I create the new FileWriter and BufferedWriter the file
             * is cleared regardless.*/

            //bw.write(AESencrp.encrypt(line));
            //bw.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

AESencrp.encrypt is just an encrypting class I have, it won't affect it. If I create a new FileWriter and BufferedWriter then this loop isn't even run (At least I do  not believe so, as I don't get the encryption of line or the original contents of the file printed, which prints if I haven't created the new FileWriter/BufferedWriter.)

```
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println(AESencrp.encrypt(line));

            /*file is cleared regardless of whether or not these are commented out or
             * not, as long as I create the new FileWriter and BufferedWriter the file
             * is cleared regardless.*/

            //bw.write(AESencrp.encrypt(line));
            //bw.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the constructor of `FileWriter` you are using truncates the file if it already exists.

If you want to append the data instead, use:

```
new FileWriter(theFile, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to append to the file, and not overwrite it.  Use the proper [`FileWriter` constructor that takes a `boolean` on whether to append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(selectedFile.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

The constructor you are using, without a `boolean`, defaults to "overwrite" mode.  As soon as you create the `FileWriter` in overwrite mode, it clears the file so it can start writing from the beginning.

Passing `true` as the second argument will allow you to append instead of overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

you open it for write (for appending use the constructor with append option). what do you expect what else should happen?
Further your outcommented `close()` is at the wrong place. it should be outside the loop.